# GATE: A working example for gate.corpora.DocumentJsonUtils

Tags: gate

I have been trying to understand how to use the JSON exporter in GATE located in `gate.corpora.DocumentJsonUtils`. Can someone supply a working example? I am not quite sure where to find or how to construct the `Map<String,Collection<Annotation>> annotationsMap` which is required by all the methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the "quick" hack that solved it for me. Not sure why they decided on this particular data structure. Also not sure why this is not done internally as a default option as it is derived from the document.

¯\_(ツ)_/¯

```
  public static String makeJson(Document doc) {

    AnnotationSet as = doc.getAnnotations();

    Map<String, Collection<Annotation>> anns = new HashMap<>();

    anns.put("MyAnnotations", as.inDocumentOrder());

    try {
      return DocumentJsonUtils.toJson(doc, anns);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
      return "";
    }
  }
```

Comment: do you have your full code for this? I'm trying to get this done using the BatchProcessApp https://gate.ac.uk/wiki/code-repository/src/sheffield/examples/BatchProcessApp.java